# Active Directory Ldap query to get all users of the same primary group of a user

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012

I need a LDAP query for windows server 2012 AD starting from the username of a user and getting all his collegues. In my AD collegues ad identified with the same **PRIMARY** group.
Is it possibile or should I need a two step query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, LDAP filtering syntax does not allow for sub-queries within the expression.

You'd have to break this into two parts - first get the user's `DirectoryEntry` record, then use his PrimaryGroupID in a separate filter, something like :

`(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=JSmith)`

Now let's say `JSmith` is part of the default "Domain Users" group (513) :

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=513))`

This will return all users that share that same PrimaryGroupID.